# Spring Transactions -Transaction timed out: deadline was Thu Oct 28 22:23:09 SGT 2021

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, spring-mybatis

Our application is a Java batch which will fetch the data from DB and CFT to dependent servers.  We have upgraded our spring libraries from Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE to 5.3.9 & mybatis - 3.5.7.After our upgrade we are getting this **Transaction timed out:** deadline was Thu Oct 28 22:23:09 SGT 2021.

> Transaction timed out: deadline was Thu Oct 28 22:23:09 SGT 2021
> at org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolderSupport.checkTransactionTimeout(ResourceHolderSupport.java:155)
> at org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolderSupport.getTimeToLiveInMillis(ResourceHolderSupport.java:144)
> at org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolderSupport.getTimeToLiveInSeconds(ResourceHolderSupport.java:128)
> at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.getTimeout(SpringManagedTransaction.java:125)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:87)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:62)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:325)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:89)
> at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:151)
> at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:145)
> at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140)
> at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:76)

We have the below configuration

```
<bean id="transManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="appDataSource" />
</bean>

<tx:advice id="appTxAdvice" transaction-manager="transManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" timeout="300" />
        <tx:method name="insert*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" timeout="300" />
        <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" timeout="300" />
        <tx:method name="delete*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" timeout="300" />
        <tx:method name="set*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" timeout="300" />
        <tx:method name="search*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="true" timeout="300" />
        <tx:method name="is*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="true" timeout="300" />
        <tx:method name="get*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="true" timeout="300" />
        <tx:method name="*" timeout="300" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Usually we will get 50K odd records and CFT the details to other server. After our upgrade one of our get** dao repo call is failing with transactionTimeout. I tried removing the timeout option for tx:method of type get* but still seeing same error.

Then I tried to remove the timeout option for tx:method=*" and I am not getting this error.
But with the same timeout with Spring 4.1.6 and mybatis 3.1.1 we werent getting this error.
Our batch job usually takes 30 to 45 minutes to complete. Now I'm getting this error after 14th minute.
I am suspecting since the propagation type of get* methods is SUPPORTS, it is reusing the transaction created by other DAO methods. Any help wrt finding the issue would be helpful. Thanks in advance.